# Why does @callback not change a variable globally in Plotly/Dash?

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash, dashboard, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly/Dash to create a business dashboard. I want it to reload data from the database every 5 minutes, so I set up a `dcc.Interval()` to trigger a call to a function  `load_data()`

Here is my code:

```py
def load_data():
    N = 100
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'category': (
            (['apples'] * 5 * N) +
            (['oranges'] * 10 * N) +
            (['figs'] * 20 * N) +
            (['pineapples'] * 15 * N)
        )
    })
    df['x'] = np.random.randn(len(df['category']))
    df['y'] = np.random.randn(len(df['category']))
    load_data_time = dt.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return df, load_data_time

data = dict()
data['df'], data['last_trigger_time'] = load_data()

@callback(Output('update-data-time', 'children'),
          Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def update_data(n):
    current_time = dt.datetime.now()
    print(f"updata data time is {data['last_trigger_time']}")
    if (current_time.minute % 5 == 0):
        data['df'], data['last_trigger_time'] = load_data()
        print("Callback triggered at every 5 minutes")
    else:
        print(f"Waiting for the next 5 minutes...")
    print(f"Last trigger time is {data['last_trigger_time']}")
    return f"last data update time is {data['last_trigger_time']}"
```

Here is the output:

```
updata data time is 2023-07-07 14:38:55
Waiting for the next 5 minutes...
Last trigger time is 2023-07-07 14:38:55
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2023 14:39:10] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 - 
updata data time is 2023-07-07 14:38:55
Callback triggered at every 5 minutes
Last trigger time is 2023-07-07 14:40:00
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2023 14:40:00] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 - # trigger, update
updata data time is 2023-07-07 14:38:55
Waiting for the next 5 minutes...
Last trigger time is 2023-07-07 14:38:55 # fail, expect 14:40:00
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jul/2023 14:41:14] "POST /_dash-update-component HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I expect that after the second call of `load_data()` the `data['last_trigger_time']` would be update to `14:40:00`. However, it remains `14:38:55`, which is be assigned at the first call of `load_data()` outside the `@callback` when I start the server. The time and data only be updated on multiples of five minutes, 5, 10, 15, ...., which is mean the function didn't change the variable globally. I've tried to use the `global` command, but according to the official document, dash does not recommend using global command. So I use a dictionary to update the data in a `def`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to declare `data` as _global_ in the callback function. See [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: @EricLavault Thanks, but as I said, Dash suggest user not to use global, so I'm seeking another way to do so.

Comment: You are _already_ using `data` as global in the callback (it is defined in the global scope and you reuse it in the function), your issue is that you have an assignment in that function's condition block which makes it local, ie. "_If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as global."_

Comment: The documentation doesn't suggest to not use the global keyword specifically, the keyword is not the important thing here. Like EricLavault mentioned `data` is already in the global scope. What the documentation warns against is situations like: "If your app uses and modifies a global variable, then one user's session could set the variable to some value which would affect the next user's session.".

Comment: Have you looked into using a dcc.Store or the other suggestions mentioned here on storing shared data https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks#storing-shared-data?

Comment: @5eb @EricLavault Thanks, now I added the `global data` command to the function, but It seems that it remains unchanged... The data still not update in the next trigger...

Comment: I understand how the `global` command. I try to trigger it manually without the `dcc.interval()` and it works as our expectation. So maybe the problem is `dcc.interval()`?